# arm-none-eabi-g++ can't find stdc++ headers

Tags: c++, gcc, arm

Whenever building a C++ source with `arm-none-eabi` (`-g++`, `-gcc`, and `-c++`) that includes a stdlib header, gcc says that the file is not found:

test.cpp:

```
#include <set>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> aSet();
    aSet.insert(abs(-1));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
test.cpp:1:15: fatal error: set: No such file or directory
 #include <set>
               ^
compilation terminated.
```

System info:
Ubuntu 15.10
GCC version 4.9.3 20150529 (prerelease)

Comment: it seems that you need to cross compile stl by yourself https://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/

Comment: @AlexHoppus that's odd, because it seems to be working on my other machine running 15.04 and arm-none-eabi-gcc version 4.8.3, without having cross-compiled anything

Comment: @AlexHoppus also the header files are all there (in `/usr/include/newlib/c++/4.9/`), and it was the header files that gcc couldn't find, not the compiled library

Comment: Actually, i have the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 with arm-none-eabi. You can use -v option, that is how you will see which dirs are scanned for includes. In my case they are /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/...  And i don't have the stl headers there. So it seems the headers you are looking at used by host compiler, and probably there is no libstdc++ on your system compiled for arm. Understand what i mean?

Comment: @AlexHoppus ok so looking at the system that I do have working, gcc needs to also look into `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/{version}/../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/{version}` (taken directly from using `-v` with version number replaced with `{version}`), which (for me) is a symlink to headers for stdlib (which apparently links in a roundabout way to `/usr/include/newlib`). So now how do you add that path to the default `<>` search path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC was looking for files with version 4.9.3, but the newlib installation has the libraries under version 4.9. Symlinking `/usr/include/newlib/4.9` to `/usr/include/newlib/4.9.3` solves the issue.

Thanks to Alex Hoppus for helping me out with debugging